# induction cooking with a homemaker 2000w cooker,

Tags: cooking-time, induction

heated supafry a solid oil, sugar thermometer on temp 2 was 140 degrees c. 3 went to well  over 200 degrees.  when food added first cooked instantly then next slower till  i put thermometer back in and it was down to 130 degrees. The unit has 9 heat settings and I don't know  how hot each one is.  What do I need to know or do so I can use this with out burning or under heating?

Comment: With any hob the numbers on the dial are petty arbitrary. You just need to get cooking and you'll learn from experience what settings will get you what you want.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Your question is pretty hard to understand; if this is important to you you should edit it to make clearer just what you're asking.

Comment: How much food did you add at once?  When frying, you're better off frying in smaller batches, so the temperature can recover.  But unless the fryer has specific temperatures on the settings, they're just a scale of how much energy it's putting into the system ... and it may not be linear.  And cooking at '4' when the room is freezing vs. '4' when the room is sweltering will result in different oil temperatures.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you're asking, so I'll provide general guidelines based on my experience using an induction cooker.

I have a single-burner induction cooker that I've used for the last four years. It goes from 160 watts to 2000 watts. I use the 2000 watt setting only for boiling a pot of water - it's far too hot for anything else, except for perhaps cooking with a wok, which you want as hot as you can get, but I haven't done that on my induction cooker.

In general, for high-heat cooking, I'll go as high as 1200 watts, perhaps 1400 watts at the highest. For most cooking, I'll use 600 or 800 watts. I'll use 160 or 300 watts for a simmer.